# Software library to render text to memory bitmap

Tags: software-development, c, text-processing

I am looking for a software library that can be used to render text to a bitmap for use in a OpenGL API-based GUI library.

It must

- Not depend on any framework like glib or Qt, It is acceptable if it requires Freetype
- correctly render diacritics
- be possible to retrieve character position given coordinates
- have a GPLv3 compatible license
- not be too large and complex. I want a simple TextOut-like function
- work on GNU/Linux
- have a C or C++ interface

Features that I do not need are

- Ligatures
- Complex script support